# Entity Framework Code First Auto Migration Fails v6.1.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF 6.1.3 and setup Auto Migration to true. 
It was working all well so far. Recently release is failing to do migration with the following error.

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +366
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass260.<FindAlteredColumns>b__257(<>f__AnonymousType2d`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier252) +184
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +232
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +275
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +436
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) +624
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) +588
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +338
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +609
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +580
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +154
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +69
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +482
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +174
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +269
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +20
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +25
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +104
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path) +209
```

When I try with clean database, it creates it all well. NO issues.
I tried commenting Seed method and tried still not working.

So this is not a seeding issue, it is failing to compare the DB changes and apply those.

How can I trace the root cause and handle it?

Comment: That seems to be related to column renaming in your migrations. If you are in a position to [roll up your migrations](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) that might help. Otherwise source code is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/5e69000553b5f910e4b739235a96d4c4a6cdaa41/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Infrastructure/EdmModelDiffer.cs).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it. Not straight forward but can be considered as a workaround.

- Change DB Name in web.config => dbname-clean
- Run the site (this will create new DB)
- using SSDT, compare schema from dbname-clean with dbname-old and sync changes
- Truncate _MigrationHistory on dbname-old
- insert into [dbname-old]._MigrationHistory from [dbname-
- clean]._MigrationHistory
- Now change the DB name in web.config to old name
- Run the site

Site loads :)